# xd_soft datetimepicker highlighting multiple time values when only one is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datetimepicker

I am using the `xd_soft datetimepicker` here: http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

I populated the time options by adding the following js code:

```
$('.my_class').datetimepicker({
format:'m/d/Y g:i A',
formatTime: 'g:i A',
allowTimes: ['2:00 PM', '2:30 PM', 
    '3:00 PM', '3:30 PM', 
    '4:00 PM', '4:30 PM', 
    '5:00 PM', '5:30 PM', 
    '6:00 PM', '6:30 PM', 
    '7:00 PM', '7:30 PM', 
    '8:00 PM', '8:30 PM'],
timepicker: true,
lang: 'en'
});
```

This is populating the correct time options, but when I select a value, every value in that hour is highlighted.  For example, if I click 2:00 PM, both 2:00 PM and 2:30 PM will be highlighted.  If I click 3:30 PM, both 3:30 PM and 3:00 PM will be highlighted.  Note, the correct value still populates the corresponding `input` element.

The issue is that it's adding the class `xdsoft_current` to two classes divs when it should only be added to one.  In the example below, if I clicked 3:30 PM, I would get the corresponding HTML.

```
<div class="xdsoft_time_variant" style="margin-top: -51px;">
  <div class="xdsoft_time " data-hour="14" data-minute="0">2:00 PM</div>
  <div class="xdsoft_time " data-hour="14" data-minute="30">2:30 PM</div>
  <div class="xdsoft_time xdsoft_current" data-hour="15" data-minute="0">3:00 PM</div>
  <div class="xdsoft_time xdsoft_current" data-hour="15" data-minute="30">3:30 PM</div>
...
  <div class="xdsoft_time " data-hour="19" data-minute="30">7:30 PM</div>
  <div class="xdsoft_time " data-hour="20" data-minute="0">8:00 PM</div>
  <div class="xdsoft_time " data-hour="20" data-minute="30">8:30 PM</div>
</div>
```

How do I get only one value to be selected?

Answer (score 1):

Use step: 30

See the issue on github:

https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker/issues/192